# Writing a while loop for error function erf(x)?

Tags: python, while-loop

I understand there is a [erf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.erf) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)) function in python. But in this assignment we are specifically asked to write the error function as if it was not already implemented in python while using a `while loop`.

`erf (x)` is simplified already as : `(2/ (sqrt(pi)) (x - x^3/3 + x^5/10 - x^7/42...)`

Terms in the series must be added until the absolute total is less than 10^-20.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you show us what you've done so far, or ask a more specific question, we'll be able to help. As for doing homework or assignments, well, we already have our own jobs =) take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works

Answer (score 0):

First of all - SO is not the place when people code for you, here people help you to solve particular problem not the whole task

Any way:
It's not too hard to implement wikipedia algorithm:

```
import math


def erf(x):
    n = 1
    res = 0
    res1 = (2 / math.sqrt(math.pi)) * x
    diff = 1
    s = x
    while diff > math.pow(10, -20):
        dividend = math.pow((-1), n) * math.pow(x, 2 * n + 1)
        divider = math.factorial(n) * (2 * n + 1)
        s += dividend / divider
        res = ((2 / math.sqrt(math.pi)) * s)
        diff = abs(res1 - res)
        res1 = res
        n += 1
    return res


print(erf(1))
```

Please read the source code carefully and post all questions that you don't understand.

[Also you may check python sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/mathmodule.c?view=markup) and see how erf is implemented